# Bugfixes between Java Version Update

Tags: java

is there a fast way to find all bugfixes between two Java releases?
For example, i want to compare 1.6.0_02 to 1.6.0_30. A list of all fixes would be awesome.
Some kind of comfort tool if this website/links:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/releasenotes-136954.html

Comment: Just check the release notes given in Oracle website http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/releasenotes-136954.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Search for `Java changelog` in your favorite search engine.
2. Click on the link to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/releasenotes-136954.html
3. Click on [Changes in 1.6.0_30](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u30-relnotes-1394870.html) to find out what was changed in 1.6.0_30
4. Repeat for every version you are interested in.

Comment: This is how I am doing it now, but this is very annoying.

Comment: Write a script that fetches the content of the pages, extract the list of changes, format them as you like.

Comment: I just did, but wanted to be sure that I am the only one with this problem ;-)

Comment: Actually I don't see a problem.